# Local variable and expression trees

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am learning expression trees in C#.

I am stuck now for a while:

```
string filterString = "ruby";
Expression<Func<string, bool>> expression = x => x == filterString;
```

How can I construct this expression by code? There is no sample how to capture a local variable. This one is easy:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> expression = x => x == "ruby";
```

This would be:

```
ParameterExpression stringParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "x");
Expression constant = Expression.Constant("ruby");
BinaryExpression equals = Expression.Equal(stringParam, constant);
Expression<Func<string, bool>> lambda1 =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(
        equals,
        new ParameterExpression[] { stringParam });
```

The debugger prints the following for (x => x == filterString) :

> {x => (x ==
>   value(Predicate.Program+<>c__DisplayClass3).filterString)}

Thanks for shedding some light on this topic.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Capturing a local variable is actually performed by "hoisting" the local variable into an *instance* variable of a compiler-generated class. The C# compiler creates a new instance of the extra class at the appropriate time, and changes any access to the local variable into an access of the instance variable in the relevant instance.

So the expression tree then needs to be a field access within the instance - and the instance itself is provided via a `ConstantExpression`.

The simplest approach for working how to create expression trees is usually to create something similar in a lambda expression, then look at the generated code in Reflector, turning the optimization level down so that Reflector doesn't convert it back to lambda expressions.

Comment: Thanks. The hint to look at the generated MSIL code is very helpful.

Comment: Something like `var hoistedConstant = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(new {Value = filterString}), "Value");` should do it

Comment: @Appetere What about `Expression.Constant(filterString)`? Admittedly, it wouldn't reflect changes to the variable, but neither would your suggestion.

Comment: Voted up, but Jame's answer was a little more on point for me.

Comment: @Appetere this is the best answer in the entire here, thanks a lot

Comment: Wouldn't this work? `var variableAccessor = ((Expression<Func<string>>)(() => filterString)).Body;`

Comment: @ShreedharKotekar: It might do - I don't really have the time to check for a question from 11 years ago.

Answer (score 10):

This code wraps the expression in a closure Block that treats the local variable as a constant.

```
 string filterString = "ruby";

 var filterStringParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "filterString");
 var stringParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "x");

 var block = Expression.Block(
 // Add a local variable.
 new[] { filterStringParam },
 // Assign a constant to the local variable: filterStringParam = filterString
 Expression.Assign(filterStringParam, Expression.Constant(filterString, typeof(string))),
 // Compare the parameter to the local variable
 Expression.Equal(stringParam, filterStringParam));

 var x = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(block, stringParam).Compile();
```

Answer (score 10):

An old question but I came to it when trying to do something similar building expressions for Linq-to-entities (L2E) In that case you cannot use `Expression.Block` as it cannot be parsed down to SQL.

Here is an explicit example following Jon's answer which would work with L2E. Create a helper class to contain the value of the filter:

```
class ExpressionScopedVariables
{
    public String Value;
}
```

Build the tree thus:

```
var scope = new ExpressionScopedVariables { Value = filterString};
var filterStringExp = Expression.Constant(scope);
var getVariable = typeof(ExpressionScopedVariables).GetMember("Value")[0];
var access = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(filterStringExp, getVariable);
```

And then replace the constant in the original code with the member access expression:

```
BinaryExpression equals = Expression.Equal(stringParam, access);
Expression<Func<string, bool>> lambda1 =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(
        equals,
        new ParameterExpression[] { stringParam });
```

Comment: This helped me a ton, thanks!  My requirements were different, but the concept of creating a "scope" class, and creating an Expression from that got in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This was really helpful