# Expression Tree how do I capture a local variable

Tags: .net, expression-trees, local-variables, constant-expression

I'm currently working towards creating dynamic expressions and I have the following scenario, which I'd like help to achieve.

given:

```
public class planet {
    public string name { get;set; }
}

class someTestClass {
    [Test]
    public void Planet_Exists_Statically(){
        var planetName = "earth";
        var planets = new List<planet> {new planet {name = planetName}};
        var found = planets.Exists(MakePredicate(planetName));
        Assert.IsTrue(found);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Planet_Exists_Statically(){
        var planetName = "earth";
        var planets = new List<planet> {new planet {name = planetName}};
        var found = planets.Exists(MakeDynamicPredicate(planetName));
        Assert.IsTrue(found);
    }

    private Predicate<planet> MakePredicate(string planetName){
        Expression<Predicate<planet>> pred = p => p.name == planetName;
        return pred.Compile();
    }

    private Predicate<planet> MakeDynamicPredicate(string planetName){
        var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(planet), "p")
        var pred = Expression.Lambda<Predicate<planet>>(
                    Expression.ReferenceEqual(
                        Expression.Property(parm, typeof(planet), "name"), 
                        **???WHAT GOES HERE???**,
                        parm);
        return pred.Compile();
    }
}
```

So my issue is that I can't get the predicate returned from the MakeDynamicPredicate to be equal to the one generated by the MakePredicate function.

I read a [reply post from Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220792), but don't understand how to implement the ConstantExpression so that the local variable is captured...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additional info: going forward I may not know the class that is being used so it will eventually be abstracted to be more generic.

Comment: If you mention some post (the one from Jon Skeet), it would be helpful if you linked to it.

Comment: sorry I went ahead and made Jon's name a link to the answer he provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you don't actually need to capture any local variable, you can just use `Expression.Constant(planetName)`.

If you then call it with, for example, `MakeDynamicPredicate("Pluto")`, the generated expression will be as if you wrote `p => p.name == "Pluto"`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I want to be able to have the expression return as p => p.name == planetName

Comment: @ermagana Why? It wouldn't make any difference in your case.

Comment: this specific instance wouldn't make a difference, but I'm building up toward a more generic design, I'd also like to be able to know how to do it in general since it should be possible, at least from what I understand.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in Jon's post you need some object to store your variable. For `MakePredicate` it will be created by compiler, for `MakeDynamicPredicate` you'll have to do it yourself. First of all we need a class for variable value storage.

```
class someTestClass {
...
        private class ValueHolder
        {
            public string Value;
        }
...
}
```

Now you put your `planetName` into an instance of the ValueHolder and make a Member Access expression for using it in your predicate expression.

```
private Predicate MakeDynamicPredicate(string planetName){

        var valueHolder = new ValueHolder
        {
            Value = value
        };

        var valueExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
            Expression.Constant(valueHolder),
            valueHolder.GetType().GetField("Value"));

        var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(planet), "p")
        var pred = Expression.Lambda>(
                    Expression.ReferenceEqual(
                        Expression.Property(parm, typeof(planet), "name"), 
                        valueExpr,
                        parm);

}
```

P.S. it often makes sense to take a look at the compiler generated code (e.g. with ILSpy) to better understand how various epxressions are created.