# C# lambda expression constant vs string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, where-clause

Can someone explain why if I run this expression:

```
const string testValue = "ABC"; 
return NameDbContext.MasterNames
    .Where(m => m.Names.Any(n => n.LastName == testValue))
    .ToList();
```

I get the expected result, however if I run the same with `testValue` as a variable it fails:

```
string testValue = "ABC"; 
return NameDbContext.MasterNames
    .Where(m => m.Names.Any(n => n.LastName == testValue))
    .ToList();
```

This seems to happen only with `string`. Similar code with `int` worked fine with both `testValue` as a variable or as a constant.

I am suspecting this is due to the object nature of string. If this is the case how could I call this expression with a variable (I don't know the value of `testValue` at compile time).

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

This query is run against a large oracle data table (> 6 million rows). When using a constant it returns right away with the proper result set. When running with the variable, it seems that the `where` is applied very inefficiently (it takes over a minute to return).

**EDIT2:**

Tracing queries in the database I see:

When calling with a constant:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT   "Filter2"."MALPHA_KEY" AS "MALPHA_KEY"
      FROM (SELECT "Extent1"."MALPHA_KEY" AS "MALPHA_KEY",
          ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY "Extent1"."MALPHA_KEY" ASC)
                                                              AS "row_number"
                    FROM "RMS"."ALPHA_MASTER_NAME" "Extent1"
                   WHERE (EXISTS (
                             SELECT 1 AS "C1"
                               FROM "RMS"."ALPHA" "Extent2"
                              WHERE (    ("Extent1"."MALPHA_KEY" =
                                                        "Extent2"."MALPHA_KEY"
                                         )
                                     AND ('ABC' = "Extent2"."LAST_NAME")
                                    ))
                         )) "Filter2"
           WHERE ("Filter2"."row_number" > 0)
        ORDER BY "Filter2"."MALPHA_KEY" ASC)
 WHERE (ROWNUM <= (50))
```

When calling with a variable:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT   "Project2"."MALPHA_KEY" AS "MALPHA_KEY"
            FROM (SELECT "Project2"."MALPHA_KEY" AS "MALPHA_KEY",
                         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY "Project2"."MALPHA_KEY" ASC)
                                                              AS "row_number"
                    FROM (SELECT "Extent1"."MALPHA_KEY" AS "MALPHA_KEY"
                            FROM "RMS"."ALPHA_MASTER_NAME" "Extent1"
                           WHERE (EXISTS (
                                     SELECT 1 AS "C1"
                                       FROM "RMS"."ALPHA" "Extent2"
                                      WHERE (    ("Extent1"."MALPHA_KEY" =
                                                        "Extent2"."MALPHA_KEY"
                                                 )
                                             AND (   ("Extent2"."LAST_NAME" =
                                                                   :p__linq__0
                                                     )
                                                  OR (    ("Extent2"."LAST_NAME" IS NULL
                                                          )
                                                      AND (:p__linq__0 IS NULL
                                                          )
                                                     )
                                                 )
                                            ))
                                 )) "Project2") "Project2"
           WHERE ("Project2"."row_number" > 0)
        ORDER BY "Project2"."MALPHA_KEY" ASC)
 WHERE (ROWNUM <= (50))
```

Note the difference in the where statement (beside the use of a variable) it tests for NULL equality

```
    AND (   ("Extent2"."LAST_NAME" = :p__linq__0
        )
   OR (    ("Extent2"."LAST_NAME" IS NULL )
   AND (:p__linq__0 IS NULL )  )  )
```

The test for the NULL is resulting in the full table scans...

Comment: Try ((n => n.LastName.Equals(testValue)), see if there is a difference.

Comment: What does "it fails" mean?

Comment: Please explain what fails, what kind of error do you get?

Comment: You should hook up logging to your `DbContext` and inspect the queries generated in both cases. Either the variable version is forcing a full table load, or its translation to SQL results in a parameter type that doesn't match the column type in your database, causing indexes to be bypassed.

Comment: Is `testValue` a simple variable, or is it actually a property of some other variable?

Comment: @rbaghbanli: Using  `((n => n.LastName.Equals(testValue))` does not make a difference

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy: I just completed some database trace. See edited question.

Comment: @Bibi, looking good, we're getting somewhere. First thing to try: `DbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true` will cause the second query to produce a WHERE clause closer to the "const" version. If it's still slow after that, it's most likely parameter data type mismatch (`:p__linq__0`).

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, I will try UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true first thing in the morning... however, in my use case eventhough Last Name is nullable,  I will never search for Null Last Names. How can I "tell" linq or the dbcontext to NOT search for Null Last Name (the OR statement)? Alternatively, how can I specify that testVlaue is not nullable?

Comment: @Bibi, that is exactly what turning on `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` does: it forces a straight `WHERE xxx = @param` clause without the additional null checks.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I think your last two comments most likely will solve the OP issue, why don't you assemble and drop an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @IvanStoev, I've done exactly that.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy setting `DbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true` worked great. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found [this article](http://code-ninja.org/blog/2014/08/20/entity-framework-performance-how-your-seeks-can-turn-into-scans/) that may shed some extra light in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theory #1**

If you have tested the generated query and determined that it is, in fact, the argument null check that's causing the full table scan, then the fix is pretty simple:

```
NameDbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

This will result in a simplified `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE "Extent2"."LAST_NAME" = :p__linq__0
```

Obviously, you will need to consider the effect this will have on other queries that use `NameDbContext`.

Alternatively you can use @IanMercer's highly entertaining solution and perform expression tree node substitution to get the desired `WHERE` clause. I expect the end result to be similar, although I'm not sure Oracle will be smart enough to produce a reusable query plan without explicit parametrization, which could result in some recompile overheads.

**Theory #2**

From personal experience (albeit with SQL Server, but since the general concepts are the same I will assume this can apply in your case) there can be another reason for a bypassed index, and that is type mismatch between your `LAST_NAME` column and the `:p__linq__0` parameter. In my scenario the column in the database was non-unicode, but the parameter generated by EF was unicode (`varchar` vs `nvarchar` respectively - unicode being the default for EF), making an index seek impossible.

Comment: Kirill, Theoriy #1: setting the `NameDbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;` in my situation worked perfectly. I will need to conduct further investigation on the implication on the rest of the application, but thank you for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this problem is to create a simple `ExpressionVisitor` that rewrites a parameter on an existing expression to a constant value using partial application.

For example, I create expressions and then apply a value (known only at runtime) to them:

```
 Expression<Func<int, int, bool>> expr = (a, b) => a < b;
 var applied = expr.Apply(input.FirstMonth);
```

And here's one of the (many) Apply methods I use (each takes a different number of arguments):

```
/// <summary>
/// Partially apply a value to an expression
/// </summary>
public static Expression<Func<U, bool>> Apply<T, U>(this Expression<Func<T, U, bool>> input,
    T value)
{
   var swap = new ExpressionSubstitute(input.Parameters[0],
       Expression.Constant(value));
   var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<U, bool>>(
       swap.Visit(input.Body), 
       input.Parameters[1]);
   return lambda;
}


class ExpressionSubstitute : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ExpressionSubstitute(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (node == from) return to;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create linq queries, you are actually building expressions trees. In your example you have two expressions trees to build your query:

```
Expression<Func<Name, bool>> exp1 = name => name.LastName == testValue;
Expression<Func<MasterName, bool>> exp2 = masterName => masterName.Names.Any(exp1);
var result = NameDbContext.MasterNames.Where(exp2).ToList();
```

From this answer [Local variable and expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220792/4167200):

> Capturing a local variable is actually performed by "hoisting" the local variable into an instance variable of a compiler-generated class. The C# compiler creates a new instance of the extra class at the appropriate time, and changes any access to the local variable into an access of the instance variable in the relevant instance.
>
> So the expression tree then needs to be a field access within the instance - and the instance itself is provided via a ConstantExpression.
>
> The simplest approach for working how to create expression trees is usually to create something similar in a lambda expression, then look at the generated code in Reflector, turning the optimization level down so that Reflector doesn't convert it back to lambda expressions.

If I define a local varaible `string testValue = "ABC";` the debug view will output:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[ConsoleApp.Program+Name,System.Boolean]>(ConsoleApp.Program+Name $name)
{
    $name.LastName == .Constant<ConsoleApp.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0>(ConsoleApp.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).testValue
}
```

Now if I define a constant `const string testValue = "ABC";` the debug view will output:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[ConsoleApp.Program+Name,System.Boolean]>(ConsoleApp.Program+Name $name)
{
    $name.LastName == "ABC"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question in full, but also: why would you call `Compile` on a simple expression (bypassing all the `IQueryable<T>` goodies and forcing a full load of the table)?

Comment: This explains why there are different behaviors for local variables and constants. I've just split this query so that it is more understandable. Anyway I am not forcing a full load of a table...

Comment: would you bet your house on that last statement? I'll reiterate, `DbSet.Where(expr)` and `DbSet.Where(expr.Compile())` result in totally different behaviour.

Comment: I don't have any house ^^ Thanks for that, I don't even know this ^^. I'll edit my post.